# Python pycurl post values to a web form really simple

Tags: python, web, curl, post, pycurl

All I want to do is convert this curl code to pycurl:

curl -d "username=Bruce&submit=Submit" "https://mytestwebsite.com/testingcurl"

So all it's gonna do is send the username "Bruce" and submit.
Yet, all the examples I've looked at have been hideously complicated.
Not quite sure why this is so difficult!

Comment: You can do it quickly with requests, I can add it as an answer if it suits your needs

Comment: That would be great. It's a Flask app (no that that really makes a difference here). But I'm just curious here as well - why is it that when you send values to a form using curl or request that the variable name (e.g. username) has to match the variable name in the function that handles the post, rather than the variable name in the form itself? Surely it sends it to the FORM, then submits the FORM, so if it's called "username" in the form, it should send it as username to the function? I hope you can see what I mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quickly and simply with `requests` module, It's simpler and easier:

```
import requests

data = {
  'username': 'Bruce',
  'submit': 'Submit'
}

response = requests.post('https://mytestwebsite.com/testingcurl', data=data)
```

As you've probably seen, with `pycurl` you will have to use the `setopt` methods and then use `perform`, `requests` is simpler.

Comment: Haha thanks! That's so much easier! I got into a right pickle with pycurl. I'm a teacher so I don't get time to read a hundred pages of manuals to achieve something that should be that simple. Thanks!